# Какую версию Alpine Linux ставить на Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

Хочу поставить Alpine Linux на Raspberry Pi 3. На странице [загрузки](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/) есть две версии **armhf** и **aarch64**.

Какую мне нужно выбрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открой архив со страницы загрузки и там есть файлы `*.dtb` - если есть файлик, с именем похожим на имя чипа и модель Вашей платы - то система запустится.

В этом файле описанны все устройства платы.

На rpi могут быть немного разные процы, на rpi3 можно запустить любой образ из прредставленных.

aarch64 - 64 разрядный, нужен для некоторых приложений, вроде mongodb.